# Python: how to get different versions of python to access the same modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scitools

I use a mac, and I have two versions of python (2.7 and 3.5). I installed scitools using `pip` and `import from scitools import *` works with 2.7 but not 3.5. I was wondering if it's because of links or something. I have included a screenshot. Thank you!

[image]

EDIT:

`pip3 install scitools` gives:

[image]

Comment: You need to install `scitools` using `pip3` in order to use it using python3

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Thank you for your quick reply. I have made an edit with a screenshot. I get an error saying that there was no matching distribution for scitools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scitools` requires Python 2.7 (source: [github](https://github.com/hplgit/scitools#dependencies)).  It's apparently not actively maintained, so don't wait around for Python 3 support.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will not wait around! lol :)

Answer (score 2):

As you can read on https://github.com/hplgit/scitools , the module dependencies are Python2.7 and numpy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and quick answer! :)