# How to access NLTK with different versions of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, python-module

I started working with the NLTK 3.0 module for Python 2.7. I have recently shifted to Python 3.6. NLTK 3.0 is [compatible](http://www.nltk.org/install.html) with both.

When I try to import NLTK using Python 3.6 (in the IDLE integrated development environment), I get the error:

```
    import nltk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

**My question:** How do I make the NLTK module available to Python 3.6 without re-downloading the module?

I think it might be as easy as changing the locations of the NLTK files, is this correct?

---

This question is very similar to this off-topic question:

[Python: how to get different versions of python to access the same modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878409/python-how-to-get-different-versions-of-python-to-access-the-same-modules)

except that, unlike scitools, NLTK is compatible with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is compatible to both, but you still need to install it for your specific python version (I'm having this problem all the time; having packages installed for another python2.x whereas I thought I installed it for python3.x or the other way round). Usually, (if you're running python3.x now), doing something like

```
sudo pip3 install nltk
```

does the trick. By "without re-downloading the module", do you mean the nltk_data folder? I'm not sure, but think that is by default put in your home folder and can be shared between different python versions. And just doing a pip install shouldn't take too long/there's not that much to download I think.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! But first I must get the pip3 command, which the following is helping me to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x

Comment: Ah yes of course. Usually the apt-get install python3-pip worked pretty good for me.